# How do you normalize a sample-by-sample processed signal?

Tags: normalization

I am writing an audio effect based on a second-order filter that adds two samples. The resulting output is clipped. So I multiplied the signal by 0.5, which results in an output that is too low. Since I am process sample-by-sample, I don’t see how you can apply normalization because the peak-values in the normalization window will vary too much.

How do you do this? Calculate the right audible half volumes in dB and add those?

Comment: Is there a change you can 'normalize' the filter so it does not add gain to your signal?

Comment: adding two samples is not a second-order filter. if the samples are adjacent, it's a first-order FIR filter.

Comment: I never said the filter adds two samples. The effect does. The filter is just one component of it. I guess I will have to limit the gain by applying a factor of 0.9 or something.

Comment: Just a small observation: a gain of $0.5$ in the signal will imply a power gain of $(0.5)^2 = 0.25$. This gain does not change the behavior of the filter, but does change the output power. If you want to leave the power unchanged, the correct gain is $1/\sqrt{2}\approx 0.7071$

Answer (score 1):

> Calculate the right audible half volumes in dB and add those?

Can't do that: dB is a logarithmic thing. Adding logarithms means multiplying the values. You want to build a linear filter, not a self-intermodulation generator, don't you?

If your filter coefficients are really just `[1 1]`, well, then multiplying by 0.5 exactly retains your original signal power for low-frequency signals. Since this is a low-pass filter, of course higher frequencies than DC are attenuated, which is not a fault of the 0.5, but exactly the result of your filtering.

A usual way to avoid clipping that only happens rarely  would be a soft-clip function that lets through any "benign" amplitudes and starts saturating "softly" towards the maximum amplitudes.

If you want to do something more "time-smooth", that would for example be an adaptive gain control (AGC), which reduces gain gradually as your signal works towards higher peaks. However, that's not a "sample-by-sample" thing, but something with at the very least memory (and often even implemented in a somewhat acausal manner).

Comment: So if I understand you right, there is no way. I just have to limit the gain somehow?